# socket.to(room).emit is not sending to the sender socket, what gives?

Tags: socket.io

According to the socket.io documentation, if I do:

```
socket.to('red').emit('Hello');
```

Everyone in the 'red' room should get the message 'Hello'. In practice, when I do this, everyone BUT the sender is getting the message...almost like I'm doing a socket.broadcast.to()

I'm using socket.io v1.1.0 on NodeJS v0.10.30